# How can a return JSON data for JQUERY datatable?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, vb.net, datatable

How can I generate JSON data for binding JQUERY data table?

I am using the below code in an ASP.net  web service (.asmx)

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Function Getcdata() As String
    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    Using con As New SqlConnection(IDvar.Constr)
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("Select * from COMPLAINTTYPE", con)

            con.Open()
            Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            da.Fill(dt)
            Dim serializer As New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer()
            Dim rows As New List(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object))()
            Dim row As Dictionary(Of String, Object)
            For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
                row = New Dictionary(Of String, Object)()
                rows.Add(row)
            Next
            Context.Response.Write(serializer.Serialize(dt))

            con.Close()
            cmd.Dispose()
            dt.Clear()
        End Using
    End Using
End Function
```

But this returns error. Kindly check where i am wrong

The error I am getting while invoking the web method as below:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type &#39;System.Reflection.RuntimeModule&#39;.
   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValueInternal(Object o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse, SerializationFormat serializationFormat, MemberInfo currentMember)
   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValue(Object o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse, SerializationFormat serializationFormat, MemberInfo currentMember)
   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeCustomObject(Object o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse, SerializationFormat serializationFormat)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem has occurred in this line:

```
Context.Response.Write(serializer.Serialize(dt))
```

You're trying to serialize `DataTable` instance directly into `JavaScriptSerializer` instance, which accepts collection objects like `IEnumerable` or `Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue)`. Usually what you need is to use `AsEnumerable()` and `[Select]()` LINQ methods to convert into `IEnumerable`:

```
Dim list = dt.AsEnumerable().[Select](Function(row) New With { Key
    .id = row("COMPLAINTID"), Key
    .name = row("COMPLAINTNAME"), 

    ' other DataTable columns here
}).ToList()

Context.Response.Write(serializer.Serialize(list))
```

But since you have a list of `Dictionary(Of String, Object)` containing objects to serialize with, just pass the dictionary into serializer instead of passing `DataTable`:

```
Dim rows As New List(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object))()
Dim row As Dictionary(Of String, Object)
For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
    row = New Dictionary(Of String, Object)()
    rows.Add(row)
Next

' pass the list of dictionary here
Context.Response.Write(serializer.Serialize(rows))
```

**Side note:**

You may try [JsonConvert.SerializeObject()](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_SerializeObject.htm) method from JSON.NET to serialize list containing `Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue)` objects, which has better capability to handle dictionary than `JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize()` method. Note that you should check the output to make sure that the JSON string is properly formatted.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. As you suggest I tried to serialize rows but it returns an empty document. I will try to use JsonConvert Thanks again!